# Need help saving value of fetch call to a field

Tags: javascript, json, formio

hopefully this is an easy one for the experts out here.  I've been doing some searching and have tried quite a few different possible solutions but this async/sync ordeal is confusing for me.

At any rate, I am attempting to fetch a JSON from an API I wrote.  I am getting the value back fine and have verified it in the console log.  However, I am trying to copy a specific value in that JSON over to a field within a form.io.

The JS:

```
fetch('https://example.com/pq-api/pq.php?date=' + data.dateOfService)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

That JSON response looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Date": "2020-08-09",
    "Time": "06:00:06",
    "Account": "Petty Cash",
    "Balance": "148.53"
  }
]
```

I am now trying to save the value of 'Balance' to a field within form.io called 'runningBalance'.  So, it would need to be something like:

```
value = jsonData.Balance;
```

Obviously the last portion is completely wrong, I only know that I need to use "value =" due to the location of this script within the form... but I can't sort out how to assign the Balance portion of the JSON to that 'value'.

Any help is greatly appreciated here!

Console Log Screenshot:
[image: Console Log]

Another screenshot when using ".then(data => console.log(data[0]));":
[image]

Comment: what are you getting at the console.log(data)?

Comment: @Menawer, I added a screenshot. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response seems to be an array to instead of doing for example

```
value=data.Balance;
```

you do

```
value=data[0].Balance;
```

Comment: This gives me the following console error: "Cannot read property 'Balance' of undefined".  I have a feeling this is because fetch is async so that data value is undefined...?

Comment: can you replace this 
then(data => console.log(data));
with
then(data => console.log(data[0]));
and tell me the answer, and yes fetch is async that code should replace console.log(data);

Comment: I added an additional screenshot

Comment: yep then the answer i gave you should solve it, just make sure to replace console.log(data) with value=data[0].Balance , it has to be there.

Comment: Yeah, I see that when shooting Balance out to the console, it's there.  I have changed the last line to:  .then(data => value=data[0].Balance);    Doesn't seem to be populating still but this could be due to some other factor.  I will explore further. Thanks for your help!

Comment: yea probably, its part of how you are reaching your element, but as you said its another problem, if you found this answer helpful, please mark it as answer, thanks